# Variable is undefined. JS

Tags: javascript, django, runtime-error, undefined

My code keeps giving me 'start' variable undefined error. I am defining it in the initGame funcion, so I don't know what the problem is. Here's the relevant code.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
var ctx = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext("2d");
var WIDTH = $('#myCanvas')[0].width;
var HEIGHT = $('#myCanvas')[0].height;

//...some variables
var gaps = new Point(5, 5)
var start;
//...more variables

//class Point
function Point(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

//...functions not using variable 'start'

function initGame(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "handler/initGameHandler/",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response, e) {
              //do something here if everything goes well
                var width = response["width"]
                var height = response["height"]

                grid_size = new Point(width, height)
                x = gaps.x * grid_size.x
                y = gaps.y*grid_size.y    
                start = new Point((WIDTH - x) / 2,
                                      HEIGHT - y);

                indicator_x = start.x + padding + chip_radius
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("error")
            }
        });
}

function startGameLoop() {
    return setInterval(draw, 10);
}


function onMouseMove(evt) {
    if (evt.pageX > canvasMinX && evt.pageX < canvasMaxX) {
        temp = evt.pageX - canvasMinX;

        var begin_x = start.x + padding
        var last_x = start.x + board_size.x - padding
        //code not using start 
    }
}

function mouseClick(evt){
    if (evt.pageX > canvasMinX && evt.pageX < canvasMaxX) {
        temp = evt.pageX - canvasMinX;
        var begin_x = start.x + padding
        var last_x = start.x + board_size.x - padding
        if (temp >= begin_x && temp <= last_x) {
            for (var i=0; i <= grid_size.x; i++) {
                var x = start.x + chip_radius + padding
                //code not using 'start'     
            }
        }
    }

}

function makeBoard(){
    rect(start.x, start.y, board_size.x, board_size.y); //throws error here

    var x = start.x + chip_radius + padding;
    var y = start.y + chip_radius + padding;        
};





function draw(){
    //code
    makeBoard()
    //code
}

initGame()
startGameLoop()
init_mouse()
});
```

I should also mention that the code was working fine before when I had the data hardcoded and wasn't reading from the server, i.e. before I implemented the initGame() function.

Data is received from the server without any problems.

Comment: Where does it say it is undefined?

Comment: You're trying to use `start` before the asynchronous AJAX function has assigned anything to it.

Comment: @putvande, Firebug console

Comment: I'm confused. I've called initGame() before startGameLoop(). I also used setTimeout() on startGameLoop thinking it was the asynchronous part causing the error but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I am defining it in the initGame function"*

No you're not. You're defining it within the success handler of an ansynchronous Ajax function that is in your `initGame()` function. The success handler will not be called until later, after `initGame()` finishes and *after* the code that called `initGame()` finishes.

Try moving the call to `startGameLoop()` into the Ajax success handler so that the loop won't start until initialisation is truly finished, i.e., after the Ajax response has been received. (You don't show the implementation of `init_mouse()`, but you may need to move the call to that function too.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `makeboard()` function is being run before the ajax request has returned. Your `start` variable is assigned in the callback of your ajax request and this will probably run after after `makeboard()` does, hence why you're getting an undefined error.

Try running `startGameLoop()` in your callback, instead of running it directly after `initGame()`.

E.g. The below would something like this in your console.

"1"

"3"

"4"

"2"

```
    console.log('1');    // I run first

    $.ajax({
         url: "/getMyData",
         success: function () {
             console.log('2');  // I run last
         }
    });

    console.log('3');  // I run 2nd
    console.log('4');  // I run 3rd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a callback in your AJAX function:

```
function initGame(callback){
  $.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "handler/initGameHandler/",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response, e) {
      // your code
      start = new Point((WIDTH - x) / 2, HEIGHT - y);
      indicator_x = start.x + padding + chip_radius
      callback();
    }...

initGame(function () {
  startGameLoop();
  init_mouse();
});
```